# set setInAnimation and setOutAnimation while starting activity

Tags: android

I have the following situation

```
TabActivity>group activiyt>(A->B->C)
```

Here A,B and C are activities. And me loading like this

```
 setContentView(this,getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("zero",intent.addFlags(Intent.FLG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView());
```

**What i need is to set animation (Slide from left/Right) when i change one activity to another?**
Currently me used the following animation, after `setContentView` to new view

```
public static Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromRight.setDuration(ANIMATIION_DURATION);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
    }
```

but it only do animation to new view.
I need like current move left at the same time new move from right
**Is there any way to set `setInAnimation` and `setOutAnimation` in startActivity like view flipper?**
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a transition animation between activities. Here is an example to make a custom animated transition after 5 seconds between splash (LaunchActivity) screen and the main menu screen in the game:

```
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            /* Create an intent that will start the main activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this,
            MainMenuActivity.class);
            LaunchActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

            /* Finish splash activity so user cant go back to it. */
           LaunchActivity.this.finish();

           /* Apply our splash exit (fade out) and main
           entry (fade in) animation transitions. */
           overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,R.anim.splashfadeout);
            }
    }, 5000);
```

Here the animations are defined in xml files, but you can create them in code as well as you are already doing it.

Your translate xml file which should be saved in anim folder in res, could look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

It moves an object from right 100% width of the screen to the left...

Comment: Thanks a lot. overridePendingTransition is what I'm looking for. But now the default animation (left->right)  making the problem. How to prevent this

Comment: can you look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988819/block-the-default-animation-for-startactivity

Comment: overridePendingTransition is accessible beginning from API Level 5. I wonder if there are any possibilities to do transitions on API Level 4?