# Block the default animation for startActivity

Tags: android

Me started an activity like this

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Second.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                        android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
```

I have set overridePendingTrasition for animation.
You can see i have set animation the *oposite to the normal* android startactivity animation.
So now this two animation get collapsed each other.
 **I want block the default animation (left->right) for while we use start activity**
Thank you

Comment: What means "block"? You want to remove it?

Comment: yes. I need only the one that i specify using `overridePendingTransition`

Comment: The animation you specify there replaces whatever animation would normally run.  You need to specify two animations, one for your new activity that is being shown, and the other for the old activity that is going away.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can prevent the default animation by setting flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION`
like this

```
mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```