# Are there some clue or instructions to implement this ui pattern in android as described below?

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns

when a indicator in tabs or actionbar is pressed or clicked, a new window or dialog shows coming from the top or bottom of the original window in modal-like effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this answer might help you: [set setInAnimation and setOutAnimation while starting activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982799/set-setinanimation-and-setoutanimation-while-starting-activity/4983616#4983616)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an Animation on a Dialog: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#tween-animation